# Powershell to Download SSRS Report

Tags: powershell, reporting-services

We're using SSRS to generate database reports that publish to an internally hosted webserver.  I'm then writing a PowerShell script that periodically runs and downloads the reports as PDFs.

I've gotten it to work running as an admin.  But for security purposes, the automated task must run as a generic domain service account.

The code I use to download the PDF using my account is:

```
 $webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
 $webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = $TRUE

 $webClient.DownloadFile($ssrsURL, $filePath)
```

When I run this code as the service account, I get an 500 Internal Server error.  I've tried replacing the second line of code with:

```
$webClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("Username", "Password", "Domain");
```

When I try this, I get a 401 Unauthorized error.  Even though the Username / Password I put in the code is my own, and works when I log in to the webserver via IE.

The answer may be in my code, domain / local security policies, or SSRS security settings...

Some questions that might be in the right direction are:

1. What other means of authentication could I try in PowerShell
2. Does anyone know of any IIS / SSRS settings I could try altering?
3. What domain or local security policies are allowing "UseDefaultCredentials" to work when run under my account, but not the service account set up?

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out... it had nothing to do with authenticating with SSRS.  My first code snippet works fine.

The issue was in the permissions of the underlying databases.  We have five reports, I suddenly noticed that the PowerShell script could download 4 of the 5 reports using the service account.  Never noticed because I was always testing on the same report...

Went to the SSRS log file to see why the last one wasn't working - the service account didn't have access to the database that specific report is pulling data from.  Hence the 500 error instead of a 401 error.